# Creating a GIF animation from PNG files

Tags: graphics, conversion, imagemagick

Is there a tool to create a `gif` animation from a set of `png` files?

I tried the `convert` command from the [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) suite, but this doesn't always succeed. Also, I have several issues with this:

1. I can't tell what the progress is.
2. No matter what I try, the `-delay` flag doesn't change the frame rate of the gif animation.
3. `convert` determines the frame order based upon the alphabetical order of the files names. This means that `name500.png` will be placed right after `name50.png` and not after `name450.png` I can fix this by adding 0's but this is annoying.

Comment: **[News]** There is a massive overlap between Ubuntu Stackexchange and Unix Stackexchange. I tried to categorize some threads [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/234217/how-to-do-gif-animations-for-instructions-and-learning-purposes-over-gui).

Comment: Regarding item 3., you can still use `convert` after sorting the files. Probably, something like this works `files=$(ls name*png | sort -n -tname -k1); convert $files animation.gif`

Comment: For Point 1: convert has a `-monitor` parameter that tracks the process

Comment: @hhc - all the categorization is just a link to an answer with 5 links; only one of them seems related, but is just a link to the above question. - A comment by @Luke gives a simple solution: `convert -delay 200 -loop 0 *.jpg output.gif`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> Newer versions of ffmpeg have no -sameq ([see faq](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html#Why-was-the-ffmpeg-_002dsameq-option-removed_003f-What-to-use-instead_003f)) but do have GIF support.
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i %03d.png output.gif
> ```
>
> Where %03d is the frame ID in 3 digits.

You may also try to use `ffmpeg` to create a movie out of a sequence of images and then convert the movie to a GIF animation (again using `ffmpeg`).

```
# cf. http://pages.uoregon.edu/noeckel/MakeMovie.html

# first convert an image sequence to a movie
ffmpeg -sameq -i %03d.jpg output.mp4

# ... and then convert the movie to a GIF animation
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -pix_fmt rgb24 -s qcif -loop_output 0 output.gif
```

Comment: This instruction is out of date.

Comment: The `sameq` option is not available anymore. Further, for me, this overwrites the original image files and does not produce a valid movie file.

Comment: What's the point of leaving the `-sameq` code there?  Why would you even want to use a lossy video format (`output.mp4`) as a temporary?  And if so, why "same quality" as the input, instead of very high bitrate?  Artifacting from that is just going to make things worse for the GIF encoder.  If you did need to use a video as a temporary, you'd want to use something lossless like huffyuv.  Or MJPEG with no transcoding, just remux the input jpegs into an MJPEG.  (`-codec:video copy`).

Comment: The `-loop_output` argument does not exist.

Answer (score 120):

ImageMagick's `convert` is a handy command line tool to do that.
`cd` to the folder containing your *png*-files and run this command:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132058

Comment: The question mentions `convert` and some problems using it. Your answer doesn't address any of them.

Comment: As of ImageMagick version `6.8.7-4 2013-11-02 Q16` this worked for me.

Comment: This works, but `10` means 10 * 10ms, so pretty fast. A delay of a `100` is 1 second.

Comment: use option `-dispose previous` or `-dispose 2` if you are working with transparent PNGs

Comment: How can you do then the reverse? Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12828048/54964

Comment: note to myself: [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) can be helpful for specifying the list of images as arguments, for example `pic_{0..20..2}.png` expands to `pic_0.png`, `pic_2.png` all the way to `pic_20.png`

Comment: @AnnevanRossum It's in centiseconds these days

Answer (score 24):

The `convert`'s `--delay` option only applies to the next image on the command line. So `convert -delay 10 *` will only set the delay of the first frame to 0.1 second. The option need to be repeated:

```
convert $(for a in *; do printf -- "-delay 10 %s " $a; done; ) result.gif
```

For your sorting need, convert does not sort frames, the shell globing `*` does. If you know your frames are numbered from 0 to 700, you can just compute the numbers yourself:

```
convert $(for ((a=0; a<700; a++)); do printf -- "-delay 10 name%s.png " $a; done;) result.gif
```

Comment: I do not experience this behavior with `convert`, for me `convert -delay 1000 -loop 0 *.png animation.gif` does add a 10s delay between *each* image.

Comment: You can also use **version sort** of the `ls` command. That is: `convert -delay 1000 $(ls -v name*png) output.gif`

Answer (score 20):

**ffmeg important GIF options + test data**

To complement [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/24103/32558):

```
wget -O opengl-rotating-triangle.zip https://github.com/cirosantilli/media/blob/master/opengl-rotating-triangle.zip?raw=true
unzip opengl-rotating-triangle.zip
cd opengl-rotating-triangle
ffmpeg \
  -framerate 60 \
  -pattern_type glob \
  -i 'tmp.*.png' \
  -r 15 \
  -vf scale=512:-1 \
  out.gif \
;
```

[image]

The test data was generated with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191978/how-to-use-glut-opengl-to-render-to-a-file/14324292#14324292

The important `ffmpeg` options I wanted to highlight are:

- `-pattern_type glob`: convenient way to select images
- `-framerate 60` and `-r 15`: assume 60 FPS on input images (`ffmpeg` cannot know otherwise since no FPS data in images as in video formats), pick one every 4 images so reduce size (`4 == 60 / 15`)
- `-vf scale=512:-1`: set the width, scale height proportionally, usually to reduce size and save space

See also:

- Video from images: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961127/how-to-create-a-video-from-images-with-ffmpeg/37478183#37478183)
- GIF from video: https://askubuntu.com/questions/648603/how-to-create-an-animated-gif-from-mp4-video-via-command-line)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.10, ffmpeg 4.0.2.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was highly useful to me.

Answer (score 8):

**Update:**

Use `convert` for the png-to-gif, then use [gifsicle](http://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) for the animation.
It's not a One App To Do It All solution, but scriptable, for sure.

---

[GIMP](http://gimp.org) can [create animated gifs](http://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Simple_Animations/) and provides control for timing/delay and repeat, etc

Comment: I know about the gimp but I don't know how to script it. Besides, the using the gimp to create animation is like killing a fly with a cannon

Comment: That's a bad idea; the quality will be horrible, as each frame will be quantized separately.

Answer (score 3):

ImageMagick can generate a good quality gif animation. Check this video - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OFusYizJ-bA

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: What a useful comment above....

Comment: `convert -delay 200 -loop 0 *.jpg output.gif`

Comment: @Luke - out of all the chaos posted under this question your comment was most useful

Comment: For me too, the solution by Luke made my day.

Answer (score 2):

ffmpeg can do it all for you but it is really hard to get your head around it. I wrote a tiny script to do the job so I don't have to remember. It runs through the images twice: pass "a" to work out an optimal colour palette, then pass "b" to actually create the gif file using the created palette.
Paste the following into a text file:

```
#!/bin/bash
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -start_number_range 999 -f image2 -i $1%3d.png -filter_complex "[0:v] split [a][b];[a] palettegen [p];[b][p] paletteuse" $1.gif
```

Save the file as "creategif", or something else to your taste, make it executable and put it in the same directory as your sequence of pngs

For a sequence foobar004.png, foobar005.png, foobar006.png...

open a command line and cd to the directory with everything in it then type

```
./creategif foobar
```

and it will create a file foobar.gif from the png's. You could add a few parameters to the script to make it a bit more flexible, but I find it easier to just hack the script if I want a different framerate or something. Many thanks to whoever it was on this forum that steered me in the right direction a few years back.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the frames in numeric order (i.e. 1.png, 2.png) rather than alphabetical, do this:

```
files=$(ls | sort --version-sort); convert -delay 10 loop 0 $files animation.gif
```

Answer (score -3):

In regards to point 2

The version of ImageMagick "display" I have (ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 2017-01-12) ignores the frame rate set using the convert command to produce the animated gif. Try another program to view the animate gif like firefox.