# Convert OGV video to GIF animation?

Tags: video, conversion, screencasting

I created OGV videos with the `gtk-recordmydesktop` screencasting program, trying to tackle this problem [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35279/typescript-terminal-recording-into-video) with bruteforce over X. I can view the videos with VLC.

Now, the task is to find some ways to convert OGV videos into GIF animations so I can display them on SE. How can I do that?

Answer (score 41):

take a look at this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/107726/how-to-create-animated-gif-images-of-a-screencast/107735#107735

..... After the **Desktop Recorder** has saved the recording into an **OGV** video, **MPlayer** will be used to capture **JPEG** screenshots, saving them into the **'output'** directory.

On a terminal:

```
mplayer -ao null <video file name> -vo jpeg:outdir=output
```

Use **ImageMagick** to convert the screenshots into an animated gifs.

```
convert output/* output.gif
```

you can optimize the screenshots this way:

```
convert output.gif -fuzz 10% -layers Optimize optimised.gif
```

Comment: For a large number of images, I had to add `-limit map 1` to convert (got a "Killed" otherwise).

Comment: With a 30 second ogv video, the convert command took all my cpu and was going for over 10 minutes before i stopped it. adding `-limit map 1` to the command did not fix it.

Comment: Try this for converting `ffmpeg -i output/00000%03d.jpg output.gif`
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/creating-a-gif-animation-from-png-files

Comment: It bears mention that direct `convert output/* -fuzz 10% -layers Optimize optimised.gif` is possible as well, and noticeably faster than the two-command path. Also, `mplayer` readily creates `png` screenshots as well, which may be preferred for captures of websites or GUIs.

Comment: How do you keep the framerate the same with this approach?

Answer (score 23):

Simple script with good quality

**Script:**

```
inputFile=$1

FPS=15
WIDTH=320

#Generate palette for better quality
ffmpeg -i $inputFile -vf fps=$FPS,scale=$WIDTH:-1:flags=lanczos,palettegen tmp_palette.png

#Generate gif using palette
ffmpeg -i $inputFile -i tmp_palette.png -loop 0 -filter_complex "fps=$FPS,scale=$WIDTH:-1:flags=lanczos[x];[x][1:v]paletteuse" output.gif

rm tmp_palette.png
```

Code from: https://superuser.com/a/556031/295664

**Without** palette: (231 KB)

[image]

**With** palette:(573 KB)

[image]

Comment: Yea very skeptical about the stated file sizes, just used your exact settings here and the file size went from 988.7k to 42.8M

Answer (score 6):

This one-liner is working for me:

```
ffmpeg -i video.ogv video.gif
```

Comment: Is this essentially different from the existing answers that use `ffmpeg`? How?

Comment: @ilkkachu I was looking for a very quick, simple and easy-to-remember solution. The other answers are much more complicated and not so easy to understand at first glance (probably resulting in higher quality results, though).

Answer (score 2):

```
ifile=~/test.ogv

echo '# Determine input WxH and FPS' 
eval "$(ffmpeg -i "$ifile" 2>&1 |sed -nr 's/.*Stream.*Video.* ([0-9]+x[0-9]+),.*[^[0-9.]([0-9.]+).*tbr,.*/WxH=\1;FPS=\2/p')"

echo '# Output multiple images from the input video'
ffmpeg -i "$ifile" -r $FPS -s $WxH -f image2 -vframes 100 -y ~/test-%03d.jpg 2>/dev/null

echo '# use ImageMagic "convert" to generate the animated .gif' 
convert -delay 20 ~/test-[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg  ~/test.gif 

echo '# remove temp image files'    
rm -f  ~/test-[0-9][0-9][0-9].jpg

echo 'Done!'
```

Comment: Suggest converting to PNG, not JPEG, larger but reduces re-compression artifacts.