# Creating a GIF animation from PNG files while constraining GIF size

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, gif

Is there a way, perhaps with `ffmpeg` or `convert`, to constrain the size of a GIF created by stitching PNG files?

This answer ([Creating a GIF animation from PNG files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24014/creating-a-gif-animation-from-png-files)) does not address this, and apparently the instructions are out of date.

Answer (score 1):

the [-layer](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#layers) option of `convert` can optimize frames and often result in gifs with smaller sizes.

this for example optimizes by reducing the number of pixels per frame:

```
convert *.gif -layers optimize-frame  animation.gif
```

also the [-colors](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-:line-options.php?#colors) option limits the maximum number of unique colors.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to explicitly limit the file size?

Comment: no, it seems that's impossible. I'll keep looking and update my answer if i find anything.

Comment: What tools / software is best practice for creating gifs (like those posted on giphy.com)? At 37 MB, what I've got is far to large to be shared on Twitter (or for that matter most web pages).

Comment: I don't know what's the best one, I use gimp it is the easiest and can also play a preview of the animation before exporting the gif.